# Notification not being recognised

Tags: iphone, nsnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to post a notification without much success!  I can do it
ok for the keyboard without issue but now am trying a custom one as
follows:

In my rootview I have this

.h

```
-(void) allowEdits:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

.m

```
//this section is run in method to present the passcode entry form


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(allowEdits:) name: @"PasscodeOK" object:nil];

PasscodeEntryViewController *vc = [[PasscodeEntryViewController alloc]
init];

[self presentModalViewController: vc animated:YES];

[vc release];


// and this is the response to the notification

-(void) allowEdits:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"notification fired");
}


// in the vc instance I have this to notify passcode was ok

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
postNotificationName:@"PasscodeOK" object:nil];

[self dismissView];
```

But the allowEdits never gets called?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try posting your notification with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PasscodeOK" object:self];
```

As sender take the vc instance (self) instead of nil. Maybe that's solving your problem.

Comment: Hi, yeah tried that before but no joy!  The problem is the method to call is in the parent and the notification is posted in the child.  From what I can see the addObserver in the parent is just being ignored!  It is driving me crazy!!!  

I just cannot understand why it wont work!

Comment: Well bugger!  I found it after all this time!  When I was implementing  notifications weeks ago I included in the viewDidDisappear method a call to remove observers!  So no sooner had I added it...it was removed!

DOH!